# Twitter follower app: "generated an exception: [{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded', 'code': 88}]"

Tags: python, twitter

I have some code that follows everyone in return when they follow me:

```
import twitter
from sets import Set

try:

    api = twitter.Api(consumer_key='',
                      consumer_secret='',
                      access_token_key='',
                      access_token_secret='')

    following = api.GetFriends()
    friendNames = Set()
    for friend in following:
        friendNames.add(friend.screen_name)

    followers = api.GetFollowers()
    for follower in followers:
        if (not follower.screen_name in friendNames):
             api.CreateFriendship(follower.screen_name)


except Exception as exc:
    print('generated an exception: %s' % (exc))
```

This is throwing up the following error:

```
generated an exception: [{'message': 'Rate limit exceeded', 'code': 88}]
```

I am aware that their is a restriction around how many followers you can follow back per hour using this code via the API, however I have manually followed all my followers back and still got the same error. Can anyone see what the issue is here?

Thanks

Comment: "manually"? As in clicking follow in your browser?

Comment: Have you tried putting something like `time.sleep(10)` after `api.CreateFriendship(follower.screen_name)`?

Comment: As an aside: `set` has been builtin for quite a while now :) So unless you're using a *very* old version of Python (and probably not as `import twitter` would break), then you can just do `friendNames = set(friend.screen_name for friend in api.GetFriends())`

Comment: @unutbu ive amended my code so that the second for loop ends with 'time.sleep(9)
             print(follower.screen_name). but now the code is just hanging there not doing anything.